# How to format data to automate table production?

Tags: r, automation

I would be very grateful for any guidance on how to use the xltabr package to automatically format tables in r, please:

https://github.com/moj-analytical-services/xltabr

In SPSS for example, I would apply the relevant weight and then run a cross tab on the raw data e.g var1*var2.

How would you go about doing this in r so that the package recognises it to produce the table?

Much appreciated.

Comment: The GitHub project page of `xltabr` gives a lot of examples and seems very comprehensive. Can you be more specific about what's not clear? Can you provide some sample data and your state your expected output?

Comment: you should paste what have you tried first, not just a problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create/ read in the dataframe which you want to use first.

```
dat <- read.spss("mydataframe.sav")
```

Then you need to put it in the format you want: As in your example of crosstables, you can do this:

```
library(reshape2)
ct <- reshape2::dcast(iris, variable1 ~ variable2, fun.aggregate = length)
#depending on what data you want, you can change the fun.aggreagte function (e.g. sum or mean).
```

Then you can use the xltabr package to prepare the excel file by creating a Workbook:

```
wb <- xltabr::auto_crosstab_to_wb(ct)
```

Then you can save it as .xlsx file:

```
library(openxlsx)
openxlsx::saveWorkbook(wb, file = "crosstable.xlsx", overwrite = T)
```

I hope this helps

Comment: Thank you very much for this. It was very helpful.